# How do i pass on control on to different terminal tab using perl?

Tags: python, perl, ubuntu, automation, perl-module

I am trying to automate a scenario in which, I have a terminal window open with multiple tabs open in it. I am able to migrate between the tabs, but my problem is how do i pass control to another terminal tab while i run my perl script in a different tab.
**Example:** I have a terminal open with Tab1,Tab2,Tab3,Tab4 open in the same terminal, i run the perl script in Tab3 and i would want to pass some commands onto Tab1. Could you please tell me how can i do this ??

I use GUI tool to switch between tabs X11::GUITest and use keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs, any alternative suggestion is welcome, my ultimate aim is to pass control on to a different tab.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to understand is that each tab has a different instance of terminal running, more importantly a different instance of shell (just thought I would mention as it didnt seem like you were clear about that from your choice of words). So "passing control" in such a scenario could most probably entail inter-process communication (IPC).

Now that opens up a range of possibilities. You could, for example, have a python/perl script running in the target shell (tab) to listen on a unix socket for commands in the form of text, which the script can then execute. In Python, you have modules subprocess (call, Popen) and os (exec*) for this. If you have to transfer control back to the calling process, then I would suggest using subprocess as you would be able to send back return codes too.

Switching between tabs is a different action and has no consequences on the calling/called processes. And you have already mentioned how you intend on doing that.